# ExtJS: put an onclick event on an element with specific class

Tags: javascript, extjs

Hopefully the title is self explanatory, but I want to put an `.on('click',function(){...})` type thing on divs with a specific class.

Hopefully this is simple and I have just skimmed over something...

thanks in advance

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use [`Ext.select`](http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/dev/docs/?class=Ext) to select [a bunch of elements](http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/dev/docs/?class=Ext?class=Ext.CompositeElement) and issue a single `on` on all of them at once:

```
Ext.select(".mydivs").on("click", function () { ...
```

From the API doc:

> Although they are not listed, this
>   class supports all of the methods of
>   Ext.Element and Ext.Fx. The methods
>   from these classes will be performed
>   on all the elements in this
>   collection.

Comment: in the function, can I refer to the specific one that was clicked?

Comment: Yes.The second argument to your callback will be the clicked element. http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/dev/docs/?class=Ext.EventObject?class=Ext.EventObject